# selecting the text in the datagrid and copying to the message box in the other php page

Tags: php, datagrid

I have two php files.notification page and templates page,in templates page,when i click and submit the item in the datagrid it should redirects to the notification page and the item should displayed in the message box of notification page.Iam trying it through reading session variables,but how to do that ?? Thanks in advance.

```
in templates.php,the submit code is as follows

    function submitUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            var $name1;

             if (row){

                        $('#dlg1').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','View');

                        $('#fm1').form('load',row); 

                        $_SESSION['id']=$name1;


                        window.location.replace("http://localhost/admin/notification1.php");


                    }
                }

notificationpage.php
--------------------

form id="parse" action="" method="post" accept-encoding="UTF-8">
<p>
<label for="api">Enter message:<br></label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" value="Templates" onclick="window.location.href='templates.php';"/>
<input type="submit" name="api" value="Send Notification">
</p>
</form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['api'])) {

if (isset($_POST["message"])) {

    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $name1 = $_SESSION['id'];
    echo $name1;
    echo $message;

    require_once('db/connection.php');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM common_notification_android");
```